# When One of 2 select boxes are changed, alert with the value for each select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following:

```
<div class="filters" id="filters">
<select id="state" name="state" tabindex="1" >
<option value="">Filter by State</option>
<option value="AL" >Alabama</option>
<option value="AK" >Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ" >Arizona</option>
etc...
</select>

<select id="availability" availability="products" tabindex="2">
<option value="">Filter by Availability</option>
<option value="yes">Available 24/7</option><option value="no">Not Available 24/7</option>
</select>
</div>
```

What kind of JQUERY magic would bind to filters, so that any time the SELECT input(s) were changed, it would alert with the Values of STATE and AVAILABILITY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#filters > select').change (function () {
    alert ($('#state').val ());
    alert ($('#availability').val ());
});
```

Comment: All these answers worked, but this one seems to be the most elegant.

Comment: You want `$('#state')` not `$'#state'`. Parens are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a selector that will choose either and apply a change event handler.  In the event handler get the value of each using a selector for each by name.

```
$('#state,#availability').change( function() {
    alert( $('#availability').val(); );
    alert( $('#state').val() );
});
```

You could, of course, get the values and concatenate them to output them in a single alert if needed.

Comment: `.vale( )` ? think you have typo in second line of .change( ) function

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to both selects e.g. class="twoselects" and apply the change event handler to them both:

```
  $(".twoselects").change(function(){
      state = $("#state").val();
      avail = $("#availablility").val();
      //now do something
  });
```